# How do i add an email address for a user who is authenticated using phone authentiation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i would like to add an email address for a user who chose phone authentication and add a phone number for a user who is authenticated using email or google sign-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#set_a_users_email_address), you can set a user's email address with the `updateEmail` method like:

**In Java:**

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

user.updateEmail("user@example.com")
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User email address updated.");
            }
        }
    });
```

**In Kotlin:**

```
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

user?.updateEmail("user@example.com")
    ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            Log.d(TAG, "User email address updated.")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can merge authentications using linkWithCredential()

> auth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)

check this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking

Answer (score 1):

Updating or adding an email is important and sensitive information, the other answers although highlight the important steps, they forget to mention that the user has to be recently authenticated for their solutions to work. If the user is not recently authenticated Firebase throws an exception - `FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException` (see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException)).

Let's walk through the official docs examples.

**Update or adding email address** ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#set_a_users_email_address))

```
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

user?.updateEmail("user@example.com")?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        Log.d(TAG, "User email address updated.")
    }
}
```

What to do in case the user is not authenticated recently?

**Re-authenticated the user** ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user))

Again taken straight out of the docs:

```
// Get auth credentials from the user for re-authentication. The example below shows
// email and password credentials but there are multiple possible providers,
// such as GoogleAuthProvider or FacebookAuthProvider.
val credential = EmailAuthProvider
        .getCredential("user@example.com", "password1234")

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
user?.reauthenticate(credential)
        ?.addOnCompleteListener { Log.d(TAG, "User re-authenticated.") }
```

In your case, the credential provider will be `PhoneAuthProvider`.

Answer (score -1):

You should add a boolean variable to the database that user has inserted email or not.
initially, the value of this variable will be false. if user signed in via phone number make this variable false else change it to true.